# Can I start/stop a specific webapp from command line?

Tags: tomcat

In particular, I want to stop `manager` when I'm not using it, and then start it up when I need it. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work-around can be to move `manager` outside `webapps` folder by issuing a command like this:

```
 mv manager ..
```

When manager is not in `webapps` folder, Tomcat will undeploy it.
To deploy manager again, simply put it back in `webapps`:

```
mv ../manager .
```

As far as I know there are no commands for handling web-applications in Tomcat.
 Hope that helps!